# Standalone webdirver vs firefox driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, selenium-firefoxdriver

What is the difference between standalone webdriver and firefox driver?

My main goal is to pass the firefox binary path to the tests. I was able to achieve this but it seems that I have to have the directConnect flag on the protractor config to true. This uses the firefox driver

Running the tests I get some failures on the assertions

For instance :

Following passes if I run using a standalone webdriver and fails if I set directConnect to true and pass firefox binary path

```
expect('Hello World!').toNotEqual('Hi!');
```

Comment: What's the difference between "standalone webdriver" and "firefox driver"? WebDriver uses browser-specific drivers to talk to browsers, there's no "standalone" driver. There's the remote driver which is driver-agnostic, but it talks to a server which knows about the various drivers.

Comment: Plus, there's nothing about selenium in your assertion. Its result should not change no matter what you do with selenium.

Comment: The tests pass when I use not.toequal when using firefox.